# How to shuffle an array in PHP so that all row are interchanged?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which is having video data ordered in descending order based on video likes. Here is my array:-

```
Array $video_order_list
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [video_id] => 1
            [video_title] => A1
            [video_like] => 120
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [video_id] => 3
            [video_title] => A3
            [video_like] => 73
        )   

    [2] => Array
        (
            [video_id] => 2
            [video_title] => A2
            [video_like] => 63
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [video_id] => 4
            [video_title] => A4
            [video_like] => 55
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [video_id] => 5
            [video_title] => A5
            [video_like] => 40
        )       

    [5] => Array
        (
            [video_id] => 6
            [video_title] => A6
            [video_like] => 10
        )   

    [6] => Array
        (
            [video_id] => 7
            [video_title] => A7
            [video_like] => 3
        )
)
```

I am duplicating the array into another array:-

```
$random_list = $video_order_list;
```

Then I want to shuffle the array, for which I used this:-

```
shuffle($random_list);
```

However, there is a chance that my shuffled array could be like this:-

```
Array $random_list
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [video_id] => 2
            [video_title] => A2
            [video_like] => 63
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [video_id] => 3
            [video_title] => A3
            [video_like] => 73
        )   

    [2] => Array
        (
            [video_id] => 7
            [video_title] => A7
            [video_like] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [video_id] => 4
            [video_title] => A4
            [video_like] => 55
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [video_id] => 6
            [video_title] => A6
            [video_like] => 10
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [video_id] => 5
            [video_title] => A5
            [video_like] => 40
        )       

    [6] => Array
        (
            [video_id] => 1
            [video_title] => A1
            [video_like] => 120
        )   
)
```

See that `video_id = 4` is still in the 3rd index (4th position). How can I check such problem?

Comment: You may use array_rand() Function

Comment: write your own function that creates new array of the same size and write a loop where you keep selecting a random value from thefirst array and if the new index doesnt match insert into new array. straightforward no?

Answer (score 1):

You may create a function checkArr() to check if any element in array is in same place or not and return false if not matched, and use shuffle() inside while loop keeping the condition as checkArr()